# The right formula of: 4 x if & else

Tags: php

I have 4 IF sentences, after that i want to say else(not the condition of any of if) but i get an error.

I have:

```
if (condition 1) { }
if (condition 2) { }
if (condition 3) { }
if (condition 4) { }
else { }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

if the condition is on the same variable

use `switch case`

its more clear !

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

else see ***Mark Baker*** answer

Comment: He didn't say anything about checking the same variable in all four conditions.

Comment: doesnt matter if the conditions are simple really jsut put the condition as the case.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (condition 1) { 
   ...
} elseif (condition 2) { 
   ...
} elseif (condition 3) { 
   ...
} elseif (condition 4) { 
   ...
} else { 
   ...
}
```

**EDIT**

The difference is that each of your "if (condition n) { }" statements (except the last) is syntactically complete, terminating with the closing } and therefore your "else { }" is only related to the very last if statement in your list.

```
if (condition 1) { // Test if condition 1 is met
   ...
} // end of if (condition 1) statement
if (condition 2) { // Test if condition 2 is met regardless of any previous conditions 
   ...
} // end of if (condition 2) statement 
if (condition 3) { // Test if condition 3 is met regardless of any previous conditions  
   ...
} // end of if (condition 3) statement
if (condition 4) {  // Test if condition 4 is met regardless of any previous conditions 
   ...
} else { // will always be executed if (condition 4) is not met, even if conditions 1,2 or 3 have been met
   ...
} // end of if (condition 4) statement
```

So if condition 1 is met, the code will still check for conditions 2 and 3, then test for condition 4 and execute the else if condition 4 is not met, ecen though condition 1 was met.

Using elseif, the else will only be executed if none of conditions 1, 2, 3 or 4 or met.

Comment: hmm i don't know what so different here from mine but it works, thx

Answer (score 1):

IF the conditions are simple id use switch/case:

```
switch (true) {
  case /* condition 1 */:
    //logic
    break;
  case /* condition 2 */:
    //logic
    break;

  case /* condition 3 */:
    //logic
    break;

  case /* condition 4 */:
    //logic
    break;

  default:
  // essentially your else logic
}
```

IF your conditions are complext then use `elseif` as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

if (condition 1) { } else if (condition 2) { } else if (condition 3) { } else if (condition 4) { } else { }

or this:

if (condition 1) { }; if (condition 2) { }; if (condition 3) { }; if (condition 4) { } else { }

Depending on what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

i think a switch case pretty much covers the whole thing:

```
switch($something)
{
   case "val1": do_something();
   break;
   default: do_something_else();
}
```

greetings